# iCalendar dtStart with value=Time

Tags: icalendar

How to define ICalendar for the below usecase,
Publishes a common classroom schedule. Note that each day starts at 9:15. [There is no start date. Just time only.]
I want something like below without using the extension types,

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=TIME:091500
END:VEVENT

Will this be achievable in iCalendar?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is non-standard:

```
Value Type:  The default value type is DATE-TIME.  The time value
   MUST be one of the forms defined for the DATE-TIME value type.
   The value type can be set to a DATE value type.
```

Reference: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.2.4

I think it makes more sense to define a date, and add a recurrence rule to make it every day, or 5 days per week.

Comment: Understood. So i have to achieve it through non standard value. Will the below is conformant to icalendar?     "BEGIN:VEVENT DTSTART;X-TIMEVALUE=TIME:091500 END:VEVENT"

Comment: No, a DTSTART property is required. See the other part of my answer.. I'd recommend including a date anyway but make it recurring.

What you're effectively looking to define is "9:15am regardless of what date it is". So an easy way to also describe that is "9:15am every day". Otherwise: why use iCalendar in the first place? The point is interoperability.